# Can an Object have 2 values?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am trying to create an object that holds parent and child objects. I need to be able to access the parent object and its children.

Preferably the syntax I wish when accessing the variables is as follows;

obj.Parent.Child.Click();

and

obj.Parent.Click();

I created an object, but i cannot wrap my head around trying to have the parent object be accessable and let it have children.

```
this.Menu = {
  Parent: "abc",
  Parent.Children: { }
}
```

But clearly that doesn't work.  Perhaps I can create some sort of Item class, or object? Please help :)

EDIT:

Okay Let me try to be more clear. Each object in the Menu, has to equal another object. This Object has a list of custom functions. Functions like *.Hover(), *.Click(), *.ClickItem("");  etc

I am trying to create an object that is easily accessible.

For example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

On that web page, the user can hover over the item and 3 sub items appear.

If I wanted to create a method in which Clicks "Link 1" in that menu, i would create the menu object first, like so;

```
var Menu {
  HoverMe: {
    Link1: page.panel.menuHoverMe_Link1, // This is a custom object, don't worry
    Link2: page.panel.menuHoverMe_Link2,
    Link3: page.panel.menuHoverMe_Link3
  }
}

// I want to click Link1, but I need to hover over hoverme before i can click link1
function foo() {
   Menu.HoverMe.Hover(); //this won't work because HoverMe = another json object filled with child objs.
  Menu.HoverMe.Link1.Click();
}
```

Comment: You need to review object literal syntax.

Comment: Why do you have `"abc"` in there? How does `"abc".Click()` make sense?

Comment: Did you mean: `Parent: "abc", Children: { }` ?  It's not clear exactly what structure you're trying to build here or what you're trying to accomplish.  Please clarify.

Comment: You said "*I created an object*". Where? And why do you think you need to give it 2 values?

Comment: This will work, but not sure if it's what you really want.  `{Parent: "abc", "Parent.Children": "xyz"}`

Comment: @Keith That doesn't allow the `obj.Parent.Child` syntax to be used.

Comment: question seems "Too broad" since one would need to teach you the very basics of JavaScript if we wanted to provide a nice answer (not a "ready to copy-paste" one). You should have a look at some JSON syntax tutorial, that would be a good start

Comment: @melpomene  I know, and is why I said not sure if it's what really want.  But it could be, nothing wrong with dot notation keys, not something I personally use though.

Comment: I made the question a little more clear, please keep in mind that in my example I used "HoverMe" based on the menu on the webpage. there will be more than one "Menu" parent object. (multiple "HoverMe"s)

Comment: This question still makes no sense. Your code contains syntax errors. There is no such thing as a "JSON object" (JSON is a string format). Please try to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
this.Menu = {
    Parent: {
        Children: {
            click: function(){
                alert('from chidren');
            }
        },
        click: function(){
            alert('from parent');
        }
    } 
};

this.Menu.Parent.click();
this.Menu.Parent.Children.click();
```

Comment: I thought about that, however the click functionality is a method as a result of the object its self.

so


this.Menu.Parent = [custom object with click method already there].

so i need parent to = that object. and it to also have children.

but the children as dynamic